# How to send array to nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

It's my first time working on an android app where I have to use Cordova, Node.js, Express and MongoDB.

My prof gave us some server side script to use.

My problem:

I have to send an array from my app to a URL that I specify to my node server. There is a "sendJSON(req, res)" method in the javascript file I was given and I'm not sure if I have to use this or do something else. This url is a location on my PC.

Here is the sendJSon code in the common.js file:

```
exports.sendjson = function(res,obj){

  var objstr = JSON.stringify(obj);
  console.error('SENDJSON:'+objstr);

  res.status(200).json(obj);

}
```

and here is my code at the client side:

//Clear the local storage and array of the user's choice of chicken type

```
function sendLogs(res){

        var server= "my_ipaddress:port_number/chicken/";

        clearFields();
        var url;

        if(chickenNumber == 0)
        {
          url = server + "Foghorn/log";
          common.sendjson(url,{ok:true,list:foghorn_items});

          foghorn_items.length = 0;
          localStorage.removeItem("foghorn_items");

        }
        else if(chickenNumber == 1)
        {
          url = server + "Little/log";
          common.sendjson(res,{ok:true,list:little_items});
          little_items.length = 0;
          localStorage.removeItem("little_items");
        }
        else if(chickenNumber == 2)
        {
          url = server + "Tweety/log";
          common.sendjson(res,{ok:true,list:tweety_items});

          tweety_items.length = 0;
          localStorage.removeItem("tweety_items");

        }
        else if(chickenNumber == 3)
        {
          url = server + "Hawk/log";
          common.sendjson(res,{ok:true,list:hawk_items});

          hawk_items.length = 0;
          localStorage.removeItem("hawk_items");

        }
        else if(chickenNumber == 4)
        {
          url = server + "bertha/log";
          common.sendjson(res,{ok:true,list:bertha_items});

          bertha_items.length = 0;
          localStorage.removeItem("bertha_items");

        }
        alert("Logs sent");
        $.mobile.changePage ("index.html#entry_page", {transition:"slide", reverse:"true"});
}
```

P.S this is a JQuery Mobile focused application on Android.

Am I sending the array correctly? Do i replace the "res" variable with the "url" variable?

This is what my prof said to do at the client side js:

"Start by defining the URL used to communicate with your node server. This will consists of your computers' IP address and port used to communicate, and then the path /chicken/. The next part will depend on the chicken breed name. Use a case statement to switch based on your chicken breed name. Then concatenate the chicken breed name and "/log" with the URL to complete the URL. When the URL is formed correctly, use the sendjason() function in the examples, to send the chicken items list to this URL. Finally loop through the chicken items and remove them from the list to clear the chicken item list of all items for that breed."

Comment: `sendjson()` contains Nodejs code (like `res.send()`), so it is meant to be executed server-side. On the other hand, you're calling `sendjson()` from the front-end, in a totally different environment, where it is not defined. In order to send data to your Nodejs server, use an ajax call.

Comment: @JeremyThille Could you please show me how to use the ajax call? I'm really not sure and I'm beginning to panic.

Comment: Really, there are examples and documentation [all over the place](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+an+ajax+call) about what an ajax call is and how to make one. Basically, you call your server and you wait for the answer. Something like: in the browser `$.post("/sayHello", {name:"John"}, response => console.log(response))` and in Nodejs : `app.post("/sayHello", (req,res) => res.send("hello" + req.body.name))`

Comment: So, the browser calls the server and passes along some data (in this case `{name:"John"}`, then Nodejs server-side receives the call on the given route (`/sayHello`), reads the name (`John`), then replies to the browser with `"Hello John"`. The browser receives this response in the callback function, and then logs the response which is "Hello John".

Comment: @JeremyThille I think I know what to do now! Thank you so much.